# How to delete first word on mutiline with sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to delete mutiline word with sublime-text.

e.g. I want to delete all the line number (there are line numbers because I paste the code from somewhere) as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use column edit mode to remove them:
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html

## For Windows with Mouse

> Select with Right Mouse Button + Shift

OR

> Select with Middle Mouse Button

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for add to selection

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> for subtract from selection

## Using Only Keyboard

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Up
>
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Down

Answer (score 7):

You can also search and replace using regular expressions. The following is tested in the Windows-version:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Replace dialog.
2. Make sure regular expressions are used: click the icon to the far left in the replace dialog or use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Enter `^[\d]+` in the **Find What** field to select any digits in the beginning of all lines.
4. Leave the **Replace With** field blank to remove the digits.
5. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

(Search for `^[\w]+` if you want to select the first word instead of only digits)

Answer (score 4):

I did this in a different way...not in Sublime though, but just in case someone is interested...there are several websites that allow you to do this! just paste your code in it with line numbers and they will be removed. I like using this one:

http://remove-line-numbers.ruurtjan.com/

Answer (score 3):

Frank He proposed one type of multiple cursor mode, column selection ([mouse instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html), [keyboard instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html)).  Another type is to use search to add additional instances ([official instructions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html#multiple-selections)). This would be especially useful if the lines you are editing are not all in a row.

In your case, you could (for instance) select a pattern from one line that is common to all lines (for example "    ").  You can then use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Linux/Windows) to select successive instances of the pattern.  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Linux/Windows) will select all instances of the pattern.

For a better overview of these option than I could ever do, see [this tutorial video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/multiple-cursors-and-incremental-search) (part of an excellent series).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a plugin (Tools/New Plugin...) that copies the clipboard into all selected regions:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class PasteWithoutLineNumberCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        cleaned_str = self.clean_line_numbers(sublime.get_clipboard())
        sublime.set_clipboard(cleaned_str)
        self.view.run_command('paste')

    def clean_line_numbers(self, data):
        data = re.sub('(^|(?<=\n))[^\S\n]*\d+[^\S\n](?=[^\n]+)', '', data);
        return data;
```

Save it in your `Packages/User` directory.

Then you can add the key binding (Preferences/Key Bindings - User):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "paste_without_line_number" }
```

Or you can just install the plugin here:
[ClipboardCommands](https://github.com/SublimeText/ClipboardCommands) then use the shortcut `ctrl+shift+;` to paste code without line number.

======

Update:

You can directly install sublime plugin `ClipboardCommands` via package control and now.